# sweep out an arc?

Tags: usage

Is ***an arc*** the complement or object in the sentence? When I refer to [sweep out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweep%20out)  in Merriam Webster, it means ***to push, carry, or lift (someone or something) with great force***. But I still have no idea of whether it is the complement or object in the sentence.

> Imagine, for example, a pendulum which swings back and forth. When it
> swings, it ***sweeps out an arc*** and then slows down as it comes
> closer to its highest point, where the pendulum does not move at all.

[No-Nonsense Classical Mechanics: A Student-Friendly Introduction](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=cIiXDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&lpg=PA33&dq=When%20it%20swings,%20it%20sweeps%20out%20an%20arc%20and%20then%20slows%20down%20as%20it%20comes%20closer%20to%20its%20highest%20point,&source=bl&ots=LReqLC-cn-&sig=ACfU3U3fs0h6ESqboKpwCgH2jyobrpkDcQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjhg_ymgoaBAxVB72EKHeFABg4Q6AF6BAgsEAM#v=onepage&q=When%20it%20swings%2C%20it%20sweeps%20out%20an%20arc%20and%20then%20slows%20down%20as%20it%20comes%20closer%20to%20its%20highest%20point%2C&f=false)

Comment: What is your understanding of "complement" and "object"? Most people understand those terms in a particular way, but definitions can vary a bit, so it's important to know how you interpret them.

Comment: The pudulum draws a portion of a circle, or maybe a curved line. Object of verb 'draws'.

Answer (score 2):

Merriam Webster is missing the mathematical definition.  Wiktionary has "construct a three-dimensional shape by rotation of a two-dimensional one about an axis",  which still isn't quite right but it is closer.

When you "sweep out an arc", you construct an arc by rotating a point about a centre. The weight on the pendulum is a point, and it rotates about the pivot. As it does so, it makes the shape of an arc.

The noun phrase "an arc" is an object.  You can debate if it is an object of a verb "sweep out" or an object of the preposition "out".  But objects are a type of complement, so this turns into a question like "is it an apple or a fruit?"